# What does the notation $N_{i;j}$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, general-relativity

What does the notation $N_{i;j}$ mean in this numerical relativity / differential equations context [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism#Equations_of_motion)?

$$ \frac{d}{dt}g_{ij} = \frac{2N}{\sqrt g}(\pi_{ij} - \frac{1}{2}\pi g_{ij}) + N_{\color{red}{i;j}} + N_{\color{red}{j;i}}$$

where $N_i = g_{0i}$

Comment: Covariant derivative. It says so in the "Notation" section of the Wikipedia article you linked.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC thank you. Just to confirm, when fully expanded $N_{i;j} = \frac{dN_i}{dx^j} - \Gamma^k_{ij}N_k$ with implied summation over k, as per https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CovariantDerivative.html?

Comment: Beats me. :-). The article also links to another article on Covariant derivative, whose Notation section seems to agree with that, but the physicists do like to proliferate their slightly different and mutually inconsistent definitions of key terms. I'll say "Yes, for now", but if you do try to do some specific calculation and things aren't working out like they should, be prepared to do an excruciatingly precise search for inconsistencies.